# Randomly generate True or False on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to randomly generate a boolean (true or false) for all the rows of one BQ table and insert into another table along with the boolean column. I am right now doing the following:

```
#standardSQL
select (case when rand() > 0.5 then True else False end) as A
```

I am not sure how to generate this for every row:

```
Table 1
Name 
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

Now I want to generate True or False randomly for each name and insert it into Table 2 which looks like the following:

```
Table 2
Name | True_or_False
XXX  | True
YYY  | True
ZZZ  | False
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL - assuming table2 already exists

```
#standardSQL
INSERT `project.dataset.table2` (Name, True_or_False)
SELECT Name, RAND() > 0.5 True_or_False
FROM `project.dataset.table1`
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the logic to a select:

```
select t.*, (rand() < 0.5) as flag 
from table1 t;
```